# Show ant design popover on row hover

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using ant design framework in my React project and struggling to show a Popover when hover any row of my Table. According to the docs the Popover needs to be created on some other component, like the following example where it's created on the Button component:

```
const content = (
  <div>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
)
<Popover content={content} title="Title" trigger="hover">
  <Button>Hover me</Button>
</Popover>
```

An then it shows like this:

[image]

My question is how to make the Popover shows for every row of a Table component if the table is created this way:

```
<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />
```

And I can't access every row individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add popup for each cell's of column with `render` property:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    render: (text) => (
      <>
        <Popover
          placement="topLeft"
          title={text}
          content="Here's pop up Text"
          trigger="click"
        >
          <a>{text}</a>
        </Popover>
      </>
    )
  }]
```

[image: Edit Basic Usage - antd@4.17.0-alpha.0 (forked)]